# Re-rendering a React component is just bad when it holds a video element

Tags: reactjs

React doc suggests completely re-rendering a React component with new `props` if those `props` have been changed due to external events.

IMHO this makes no sense. If the React component holds a video element (whose `src` attribute has not changed) re-rendering it means that the video is destroyed and created again.

So, which is the proper way to deal with this scenario?

**UPDATE:** Forget my question, it's wrong. The video element is not destroyed and created every time props change.

Answer (score 4):

For this exact reason there is the component lifetime method [shouldComponentUpdate](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-shouldcomponentupdate).

Comment: I don't understand. AFAIU "re-rendering" a component does not mean calling `setState()` on it, but destroying it (and its DOM children) and creating a new one with the updated `props`.

Comment: Have a read of this  (https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html). The TL;DR version is that shouldComponentUpdate needs to be a meaningful predicate of whether your `nextState` and `nextProps` are equal to your current. If they aren't, then the component will re-render, if they are, it won't. N.B. the paragraph about object references and `shouldComponentUpdate`.